# MySQL query only fetching the first row instead of all the rows in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch multiple rows in MySQL database but it is fetching only the first entry!

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl") 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    { 
            $desc = $info['description'];
            $screen_name1 = $info['screen_name'];
            $final_oauth_token = $info['final_oauth_token'];
            $final_oauth_token_secret = $info['final_oauth_token_secret'];

    );
```

So I get only 1 row but I need to get multiple rows as every row has got its unique screen_name and description.

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: How are you outputting this on your webpage?

Comment: actually it is getting multiple rows.but you are replacing them with the new value everytime in the loop.instead of strings try saving them in an array

Comment: while loop enclosed in `{}` and dont use `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to place it in a container that would display the results on your webpage

Try This:

```
       echo "<table>";

       $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl");

       while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
       { 
          $desc = $info['description'];
          $screen_name1 = $info['screen_name'];
          $final_oauth_token = $info['final_oauth_token'];
          $final_oauth_token_secret = $info['final_oauth_token_secret'];

         echo "
         <tr>
            <td>".$desc."</td>
            <td>".$screen_name1."</td> 
            <td>".$final_oauth_token."</td>
            <td>".$final_oauth_token_secret."</td>
         </tr>";

         }
         echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct code to this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl"); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    { 
           echo $desc = $info['description'];
           echo $screen_name1 = $info['screen_name'];
          echo  $final_oauth_token = $info['final_oauth_token'];
          echo  $final_oauth_token_secret = $info['final_oauth_token_secret'];

    }
```

Comment: I've added echo. While I run the php code the console reads 'Internal server error'. What is to be done?

Comment: The page have any problem? Did you tried to echo anything at the start of the page. Also check whether the sql is correct and have values by echoing the query and executing it in database.

Answer (score 2):

While statements are enclosed within {} not {);

Edited:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl") 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{ 
        Echo $desc = $info['description'];
        Echo $screen_name1 = $info['screen_name'];
        Echo $final_oauth_token = $info['final_oauth_token'];
        Echo $final_oauth_token_secret = $info['final_oauth_token_secret'];

}
```

Comment: `echo` all the variables

Comment: well the end syntax --> ); was by mistake while typing. I've used echo as well. While I run the php code the console reads 'Internal server error'. What is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Adding data into array.
what is your target? (Store data? echo?)

CODE:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl");


if($data && mysql_num_rows($data) > 0)
{
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    { 
            $desc[$i] = $info['description'];
            $screen_name1[$i] = $info['screen_name'];
            $final_oauth_token[$i] = $info['final_oauth_token'];
            $final_oauth_token_secret[$i] = $info['final_oauth_token_secret'];

        ++$i;

    }

    unset($i, $info, $data);
}
```

Or like Echo mode

CODE:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl");


if($data && mysql_num_rows($data) > 0)
{

    $x = "
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>
        desc
      </th>
      <th>
        screen_name
      </th>
      <th>
        oauth Token
      </th>
      <th>
        secret oauth Token
      </th>
   </tr>";


    //Warning it's eat a lot of memory
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    { 


            $x .= "
   <tr>
      <td>
        {$info['description']}
      </td>
      <td>
        {$info['screen_name']}
      </td>
      <td>
        {$info['final_oauth_token']}
      </td>
      <td>
        {$info['final_oauth_token_secret']}
      </td>
   </tr>";

    }

    $x = "
</table>";

    echo $x;

    unset($info, $data, $x);
}
```